# Is it good practice to use ASP.NET MVC without a View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

We're planning to build a web service to retrieve and send data to an external application.

Someone suggested we use the ASP.NET MVC project.  Thing is, we won't have a view.  All we're doing is a query and returning the output to the caller. I questioned the use of this project.

He responded that you don't need a view to utilize a MVC project. He added that we can take advantage of the URL routing feature. However, I'm still skeptical.

Is there any reason to choose ASP.NET MVC over a Web API considering we won't utilize the View?

Answer (score 2):

You aren't required to use views (or models for that matter) in MVC. In this case both MVC or Web API would work equally well. There is no advantage of one over the other if you are not using views.

Do note that in ASP.NET Core there is now no difference at all - there is only 1 framework to use and it can be used with or without views.

Comment: To add to this, before Core, Web API would just give you a REST based way of making calls, or you could use the MVC way and do RPC.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really want to make some service it's most probably helpful when you use web API. True, it's not necessary to have views in asp.net MVC and also routing is working more similar in both.

The thing is, if you need to authenticate the calls there is little difference how we authenticate calls. Normally web API has come with token-based authentication rather than using cookies use in asp.net MVC.

Answer (score 0):

For your current requirement, the best solution is **WebAPI**.

You should use **MVC controller** if you are going return a view. You can return data also from **MVC Controller**, but is better to user **WebAPI controller** if you wish to return only data(you can use it like a **HTTP service**).

The Advantage of using **WebAPI** is I can say it is a light weight. Hence you can go with **WebAPI**